# Licenciamento: Como lidar com adulterações da data/hora local de um computador?

Tags: windows, data, sistema-operacional, licença

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação (Desktop) que requer renovação de licença periodicamente, seguindo um modelo [SaaS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_como_servi%C3%A7o).

O modelo da licença deverá funcionar da seguinte forma:

- A licença será baixada de um serviço Web. Isto requer que o usuário esteja conectado à internet no primeiro uso do produto;
- A licença será atualizada periodicamente por um processo background automático, conectando ao serviço e renovando a data de expiração;
- Se o usuário em questão romper a assinatura (deixar de pagar) ou não se conectar mais ao servidor de licenciamento, poderá usar o produto até uma data determinada (data de validade da última licença baixada).

Neste caso, como lidar com adulterações na data/hora local da máquina, de modo que o usuário seja impedido de usar o produto mesmo retroagindo o relógio do seu computador?

Comment: Se o seu sistema for totalmente offline, tem um misto de técnicas. Uma delas é você armazenar a quantidade de uso do sistema, vinculada a algum dado recém inserido. Mesmo que a data seja alterada, não tem como voltar atrás com as "horas consumidas". Se seu sistema for online, basta consultar a data e hora externamente, de preferência de um servidor seu, com alguma chave para fazer checksum da requisição.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Se o usuário em questão romper a assinatura (deixar de pagar) ou não se conectar mais ao servidor de licenciamento, poderá usar o produto até uma data determinada (data de validade da última licença baixada).

Não utilize datas determinadas. Utilize **número de dias**. Por exemplo, cada pagamento mensal dá direito ao uso por 28-31 dias.

A cada boot-up do seu serviço:

- valide o momento da última atualização versus o momento atual.

  - Se a data for diferente (passado ou futuro, tanto faz) *remova um dia*.
  - Se a hora do sistema for *inferior* (o relógio foi manipulado), *remova um dia*.
- Armazene o momento atual, para que esta possa ser validado no próximo boot-up.

Assim, tentativas de burlar o contador sempre contarão *contra* o usuário malicioso, porém sem prejudicar o usuário honesto.

Como @Bacco originalmente mencionou em seu comentário (o crédito é seu, Bacco!), é interessante que você valide esta estrutura contra alguma outra fonte para evitar a reinicialização do arquivo contendo o momento da última avaliação. A solução que ele apresenta (armazenando no arquivo encriptado o último ID de uma tabela conhecida e frequentemente utilizada para operações de escrita do banco de dados, por exemplo) é simples, robusta e de fácil implementação.

Soluções como um servidor remoto NTP (hora da rede) ou um endpoint que retorne a data atual de maneira encriptada (e que deve necessariamente ser acessível ou o usuário perde acesso imediato) são viáveis e dependem do modelo que você deseja utilizar.

Answer (score 3):

Tem diversas formas de fazer.

Uma que eu recomendo é que você marque a data e hora de entrada e de saída do seu sistema.
Se ele voltar mais de duas horas do que o último horário de saída, você pede pra ele reconectar para voltar a validar a licença e sem isso bloqueia o acesso.

O pior caso desse método é ele conseguir utilizar por 30 dias contínuos (gerenciando suporte bem a data e hora do sistema todas as vezes e tendo um trabalhão extra).

Uma outra opção é varrer o sistema e olhar data e hora de um ou diversos arquivos do sistema operacional e do seu programa pra dar uma olhada se há alguma inconsistência.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode comparar com a base de dados da própria aplicação verificando se não existe registros com data e hora mais recente do que a data configurada no computador local. Pois se a data foi adulterada uma hora as datas dos registros da base começarão a dar divergências.

Exemplo:

Vamos supor que a data adulterada foi fixada em 29/02/2016.
Em determinada tabela gerou os seguintes registros:

29/02/2016 08:00:00, 
29/02/2016 09:00:00, 
29/02/2016 13:00:00 e
29/02/2016 18:37:00

Amanhã ao ser utilizada a aplicação a data continuara sendo 29/02/2016 (ou alguma data menor). Vamos supor que foram gerados novos registros nesta tabela:

29/02/2016 10:30:00

Percebe a inconsistência? Como que estou inserindo um registro no dia 29/02/2016 as 10:30 se eu já tenho registros neste mesmo dia com horários superiores. Neste caso esta detectada a inconsistência e você pode dar um crash na aplicação pois é sinal que estão tentando burlar o sistema de licença.

Você pode ter uma tabela na aplicação só para registrar as horas a cada hora e criar uma rotina para detectar a inconsistência ou pode utilizar até mesmo alguma tabela já existente que tenha data e hora e gere registros com certa frequência.

Outra opção pode ser também comparar com os logs de eventos de aplicação do windows (Event Viewer) ao invés de usar sua base.