# O que é e para que serve um checksum?

Tags: algoritmo, independente-de-linguagem

Eu estava lendo [uma pergunta aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115819/18246) e me deparei com o termo ***checksum***.

Várias outras vezes eu já vi este termo sendo usado quando se fala em transferência de arquivos ou de algum dado importante.

Afinal, o que é e para que serve o tal do *checksum*? Gostaria de algum exemplo simples (dou preferência para C#, mas pode ser qualquer linguagem) de como fazer um *checksum*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Em poucas palavras, o *checksum* serve para verificar, por exemplo, se um arquivo é exatamente o mesmo arquivo depois de uma transferência. Para verificar se não foi alterado por terceiros ou se não está corrompido.

A ideia é, por exemplo, pegar nos bytes todos de um arquivo e somá-los, um a um, e obter um valor, o *checksum*. Depois de uma transferência, esse valor do *checksum* deve ser o mesmo tanto no arquivo enviado pelo remetente quanto no recebido pelo destinatário. Mesmo assim, pode não ser garantido que o arquivo é exatamente o mesmo. Por isso, há várias formas de fazer essa soma.

Na minha empresa, por exemplo, utilizamos o [`md5sum`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/md5sum.1.html) que utiliza o algoritmo MD5 para calcular o *checksum* para que os nossos clientes possam garantir que estão a usar a versão correta do nosso *software*, depois de o transferirem basta-lhe fazer a verificação do arquivo com o [`md5sum`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/md5sum.1.html).

Exemplo:

<kbd>[image: diagrama demonstrando o checksum]</kbd>

<sup>[fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum)</sup>

Comment: @DiegoSantosSeabra Sua edição trouxe um pouco de controvérsia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5629/132

Answer (score 13):

Como os colegas já bem explicaram em outras respostas, o *checksum* serve essencialmente para verificar a integridade de uma sequência de dados (tanto faz se é em uma transmissão via rádio, Internet, sinal de fumaça, etc, ou em um arquivo no disco, enviado para alguém por email ou disponível para download).

Eu só resolvi responder porque gostaria de fornecer uma *intuição* por detrás do assunto. A palavra inglesa *checksum* significa exatamente "soma" (*sum*) de/para "verificação" (*check*), porque o princípio dos algoritmos é o seguinte:

1. Objetiva-se produzir um valor numérico, facilmente calculado por ambos os lados de uma transmissão (isto é, tanto pelo emissor como pelo receptor), e que represente não apenas o conteúdo existente no arquivo como também a ordem em que esse conteúdo se encontra.
2. Uma vez tendo-se esse valor calculado pelo emissor, o arquivo (ou pacote de dados) é transmitido juntamente com o valor do *checksum*. O receptor recalcula o valor para o arquivo/pacote recebido e compara com o valor original enviado pelo emissor. Se for diferente, ocorreu algum problema na transmissão (por exemplo, um byte qualquer foi alterado, talvez por ruídos no meio de transmissão ou mesmo por má fé de um terceiro).

E como o valor de um *checksum* representa o conteúdo e a ordem em um conjunto de dados? Há várias formas. Uma bem inocente, e que na prática serve apenas de ilustração didática, é a seguinte:

> Percorre-se os caracteres do arquivo/pacote do início ao fim,
>   multiplicando-se o valor do caractere (seu valor ASCII, por exemplo)
>   pelo índice (a posição do caractere na sequência percorrida). Esse
>   resultado é então acumulado em um valor total (o tal *checksum*). Deve
>   ser fácil perceber que se qualquer caractere for alterado (um `A` vira
>   um `X`, por exemplo) ou mudar de posição (a sequência `ABC` vira
>   `BCA`, por exemplo), o valor da multiplicação `[valor do caractere] * [índice]` vai ser diferente naquela posição, incorrendo em que o *checksum* resultante de todo o pacote vai *necessariamente* ser diferente.

Exemplo de código C++ que faz esse cálculo para uma string de dados `s` (sem necessariamente considerar o `\0` como terminação da string, por isso a função `simpleCheckSum` espera um tamanho alocado na variável `size`):

```c++
#include <stdio.h>

long long simpleCheckSum(char *s, int size)
{
    long long chkSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        chkSum += (s[i] * i);
    return chkSum;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("CheckSum de 'ABC': %lld\n", simpleCheckSum("ABC", 3));
    printf("CheckSum de 'AbC': %lld\n", simpleCheckSum("AbC", 3));
    printf("CheckSum de 'BCA': %lld\n", simpleCheckSum("BCA", 3));

    return 0;
}
```

Resultado desse código:

```
CheckSum de 'ABC': 200
CheckSum de 'AbC': 232
CheckSum de 'BCA': 197
```

Observe que esse algoritmo, apesar de funcional, é bem inocente e pode não servir para arquivos/pacotes muito longos (porque o número resultante tende a crescer bastante). Ele foi usado apenas para ilustrar o princípio. Os algoritmos mais comuns utilizados na prática são descritos [na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum#Checksum_algorithms), e nas respostas que você já obteve.

Comment: Uma dúvida: a assinatura do primeiro método é realmente `long long simpleCheckSum(...)` ou deveria ser só um `long`?

Comment: @jbueno É `long long` mesmo, já que os valores retornados podem ser realmente grandes (um tipo integral com *ao menos* 64 bits: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18971808/2896619).

Comment: Legal, @LuizVieira. Como eu não entendo de C++, fiquei na dúvida. Aliás, muito obrigado pela resposta! Ficou ótima.

Answer (score 8):

Checksum ou soma de verificação serve para ajudar a garantir a integridade de pacotes de uma comunicação ou assegurar que um arquivo não foi corrompido.

No cabeçalho, é feito um cálculo pré combinado com base em todos os bits significativos do pacote e o resultado é enviado também na comunicação para poder ser feita a comparação do outro lado.

Por exemplo, se no protocolo de comunicação serial, fizermos o envio de um comando, dois bytes de payload (dados do comando) e o byte de checksum somando todos os valores, teríamos que mandar o comando seguindo esta regra.

Para mandar o comando 0x01, e payload de 0x00, 0x00 teríamos que o checksum é 0x01 e este seria enviado no final. Ao abrir os bytes do outro lado, você consegue ter maior certeza de que todos os bits estão corretos, porque sua soma também deu 0x01. Se um bit qualquer alterar, o checksum não coincidiria mais.