# Função para criar hash no padrão SRI

Tags: php, segurança, hash, openssl, cors

Estava a olhar para uma nova especificação [W3C SRI (Subresource Integrity)](http://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) o que a grosso modo quer dizer **Integridade do Sub-recurso** que promete trazer mais segurança a recursos hospedados em servidores de terceiros (ou no próprio) ja em uso por **BootstrapCDN**, **CloudFlare**, **GitHub** e **jQuery** embora ainda seja nova e não tenha uma ampla implementação pelos navegadores.

Basicamente a nova especificação adiciona a tag `script` dois novos atributos:

- **integrity**: que contém a `hash` criptográfica do arquivo
- **crossorigin**: por padrão "anonymous"

A documentação (simplista) descreve o uso de `OpenSSL` via linha de comando para criar a `hash`:

**Instrução de linha de comando para gerar a hash**

```
openssl dgst -sha384 -binary FILENAME.js | openssl base64 -A
```

Minha questão é: como usar a funções `openssl` do `PHP` para chegar ao mesmo resultado (gerar a hash de um arquivo)?

**Referencias:**

- **[SRI Hash Generator](https://www.srihash.org/)**: ferramenta online
- **[W3C Subresource Integrity](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/)**: especificação
- **[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=subresource-integrity)**: suporte
- **[Mozila Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity)**: documentação
- **[Mozila Hacks](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/subresource-integrity-in-firefox-43/)**: artigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem o `hash_file()` no PHP, que a variação do `hash()` justamente para arquivos, que é similar ao *morto* `md5_file()`.

```
$algoritmo = 'SHA512';
$arquivo = 'arquivo.js';

$hash = hash_file($algoritmo, $arquivo, true);

$integrity = strtolower($algoritmo) . '-' . base64_encode( $hash );
```

Dessa forma basta utilizar:

```
<script src="' . $arquivo . '" integrity="' . $integrity . '" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

---

Obviamente deveria de calcular isto previamente, porque executar isto a cada página visitada é desperdício, gastar tempo para calcular *uma mesma hash* sempre...

Não vejo muito sentido em utilizar isto para um mesmo domínio, porque se alguém tiver acesso ou conseguir alterar o conteúdo o javascript muito possivelmente conseguirá mudar a *hash* do HTML, assim tornando o novo JavaScript válido.

Se utiliza CDN (ou outro servidor) para distribuir o javascript ou se você vai permitir que outras pessoas incorporem o seu javascript tem um grande sentido utilizar este recurso, porque nesta situação se alguém alterar o seu arquivo os seus clientes terão a HASH do arquivo.

---

O uso desse recurso impediria/minimizava o ataque que teve ao "Site Blindado", que  modificou a imagem, mostrando outro resultado, isso ocorreu em 2012, [veja aqui](http://www.linhadefensiva.org/2012/10/site-de-selo-de-seguranca-site-blindado-e-invadido-por-hackers/), todos os clientes do "Site Blindado" tiveram suas páginas mostrando o conteúdo alterado, um logo "Site Blindado Hackeado", devido a não haver algum tipo de verificação.

Comment: Vale ressaltar a correção: a especificação `SRI` exige que o descriminador do algorítimo utilizado seja em `lowercase` e o valor encodado em `base64` seja um `binário`.

Comment: Quanto a uso: os `scripts` e seus atributos são montados em `PHP` e cacheados com `OPcache` para serem utilizados em outras páginas sem desperdício de recursos... quanto a acesso não autorizado ou invasão bom, está especificação não mitiga os danos decorrentes disto.

Comment: Corrigi para forçar a letra minuscula. Sobre as "invasões" o que quis dizer é que ela reduz o alcance do dano. Imagine que o você utiliza o JQuery do GoogleApis. Se o Google "for invadido" (ou MITM) e alterar a a biblioteca do JQuery o seu website pode apresentar o javascript malicioso em seu lugar. Com o uso deste recurso a hash de ambos os arquivos serão diferente, o arquivo malicioso terá uma hash diferente do arquivo original, assim prevenindo que os visitantes do seu site usem o JS malicioso, logo podemos dizer que em caso de invasões em SERVIDORES TERCEIROS ele reduz os danos.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil ter mudado **SHA512** para **sha512** ao invés do uso de `strtolower()`? Deve-se adicionar um terceiro argumento a função `hash_file()` (`{boolean} true)` para ela retornar um **binário**. Saberias informar qual função (`openssl_digest()`, `hash()` ou `hash_file()`) tem menos custo de processamento? Grato

Comment: Do jeito que esta seu exemplo ta dando erro

Comment: Fiz a correção, não me atendei este detalhe. O `hash()` é para *textos*, você utilizar o `file_get_contents` deve ser mais lento do que o `hash_file`, que deve fazer a mesma tarefa em C, *muito mais rápido do que PHP*. O OpenSSL não sei, pessoalmente evito utiliza-la, mas acredito que deve ser tão rápida quanto. Eu utilizei o `strtolower` porque evita erro humano, se depender de alguém digitar em minusculo ou maiúsculo a chance de falha seria maior, alguém poderia cair aqui e não notar que tem que ser minusculo, usando o `strtolower` de qualquer forma será minusculo.

Answer (score 0):

Ao pesquisar na comunidade sobre [SRI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=SRI) não obtive resultados por isso deixo minha própria resposta.

De maneira prática cheguei ao resultado de duas maneiras em `PHP`:

```
<?php

   $file = file_get_contents('./main.js');

   echo "sha512-".base64_encode(openssl_digest($file, 'sha512', true));

   //output: sha512-4nAOca/W9ZDO2dwcudh/hbnatmbvezf5ZTti0+VZFDG+V65tDx8OeKIpZfG7NYvOjqytEveULALcb7ZbPAuF/Q==


   $hash = hash('sha512', $file, true);

   echo "sha512-".base64_encode($hash);

   //output: sha512-4nAOca/W9ZDO2dwcudh/hbnatmbvezf5ZTti0+VZFDG+V65tDx8OeKIpZfG7NYvOjqytEveULALcb7ZbPAuF/Q==
```

Ambos retornam o mesmo resultado, caberia aqui testar performance.

**Referencia:**

Neste [artigo do site tenzer.dk](https://tenzer.dk/generating-subresource-integrity-checksums/) o autor indica ter observado o código fonte do site [SRI Hash Generator](https://www.srihash.org/) e adaptou a lógica para outras linguagens entre elas:

- **Shell**
- **Python**
- **Node.js**
- **Go**
- **Ruby**
- **PHP**

E como a especificação trata de usar um `checksum` vale passar por esta [referencia aqui da comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115905/o-que-%C3%A9-e-para-que-serve-um-checksum).

É isso.